# how to send dataset Input - outputparameter to progress from .net

Tags: c#, progress-4gl

So my Colleague has written a simple web service in progress which expect from me as input parameter - > dataset. here is the web service

```
Define TEMP-TABLE TTList NO-UNDO
       FIELD  CtrlName          AS CHAR
       FIELD  WrdNr             AS INT
       FIELD  Descr             AS CHAR
       FIELD  DescrShort        AS CHAR
       FIELD  DescrTooltip      AS CHAR

       FIELD TRecid             AS INT
       .

DEFINE DATASET ds FOR TTList.

DEFINE INPUT        PARAMETER pCoCd                         AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE INPUT        PARAMETER pLanCd                        AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE INPUT        PARAMETER pUsrCd                        AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE INPUT        PARAMETER pFilter                       AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE INPUT-OUTPUT PARAMETER DATASET                       FOR ds.
DEFINE       OUTPUT PARAMETER pErrorTxt                     AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

DEFINE STREAM sLOG.

{ RunSupersOnAppServer.i }

FOR EACH TTList WHERE TTList.WrdNr <> 0:

    RUN Super-Find-Wrd  ( INPUT pLanCd             ,
                          INPUT TTList.WrdNr       ,
                          INPUT ""                 ,
                         OUTPUT TTList.Descr       ,
                         OUTPUT TTList.DescrShort  ,
                         OUTPUT TTList.DescrTooltip).
END.

RETURN.
```

SO my question is : can someone help me how to construct this dataset/xmlDocument from c#/.net and send it so progress can unnderstand it

Comment: Do you plan to call a web service or do you want to do this via a Openedge .Net Proxy?

Comment: I plan to call this Progress web service from mvc .net and as you see I should give it as parameter data set

Comment: There's an entire chapter on this in the documentation. Check specifically "Developing a .NET Client to Consume OpenEdge SOAP Web Services" and the part "Creating .NET DataSets from ProDataSet parameters" in http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge113/pdfs/dvwsv/dvwsv.pdf